# SelectAll only current(visible) page using angular

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I trying to select all records on current page but records are selected across all the pages. Could you please suggest me how we can select only current page. Please refer attached Stackblitz for demo.

```
 isChecked = false;
  checkuncheckall() {
    if (this.isChecked == true) {
      this.isChecked = false;
    } else {
      this.isChecked = true;
    }
    if (this.persons && this.persons.length) {
      this.persons.forEach(f => (f.check = this.isChecked == true));
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-population-hw5yef?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Get current page data then check/uncheck

```
 dtInstance
    .rows({
      page: "current"
    })
    .data()
    .toArray()
    .forEach(f => (f.check = this.isChecked == true));
```